# iPhone: can i use NSString search in NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can i use like this r not

```
for (NSString *string in userInfo){


        lblUserName.text = (NSString *) [userInfo objectForKey:@"name"];

        lblLocation.text = (NSString *) [userInfo objectForKey:@"location"];

        lblDescription.text =(NSString *) [userInfo objectForKey:@"description"];


    NSLog(@"User profileData Received: %@", userInfo);

    }
```

here userInfo = NSArray (this is delegate i can change )

lblUserName = label name

ObectForKey is using for searching NSString

thank you, is this Right r wrong one

if not how i have to work out

Comment: I don't understand you code. Please `NSLog(@"%@", userInfo)` to show what it really is.

Comment: You can take the value from NSArray. If userInfo is NSArray you can use for(NSString *string in userInfo). If userInfo is already NSDictionary than you can directly use the [userInfo objectForKey:@"name"];. I mean you are mixing up the concept here.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with this code. You are iterating over userInfo using a variable named "string" but you never use this variable in the for statement. Also you use userInfo as a dictionary but you say it's an array.

Comment: hi julien,this is tweet app's deleage method in that, NSArray will be, i get userInformation in to userInfo array this array is in deleage method and userInfo(array) contain all information about user, this userInformation have to show on UIElements (no. of tweets count, name on Label, image on UIImageView ). all info in userInfo array, by using NSLog i am print on debug console, to show on UIElement, i have to COPY into DICTIONARY and come compare with string and Keep on UIElements, canTellMe how to work this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSArray are not key based but index based.  Use NSDictionary instead or use index to retrieve items.

and I don't understand what is the loop for, you don't even use the string var in it ???

Comment: hi desmed, in tweet app there is delegate for retriving the user information and in that delegate, array will be, all the info will stores(for displaying when app runs) so that i have to store the array info in NSDictionary and comparing with string and getting the values and display in screen. can you suggest me. HOW TO STORE NSARRAY IN NSDictionary